# построение разрывного графика

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Пытаюсь визуализировать данные из `dataframe` с помощью `Matplotlib`,

изначально имею `df` следующего формата:

| date | name | total | ok |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

изначально данные в таблице сгруппированны по часам, но, если за какой-то момент не было данных строки с наименованием часа отсутствует, соответвено подготавливаю данные следующим образом:

```
def prepare_axis(df):
    # вычисляю диапазон
    start_date = df['date'].min()
    end_date = df['date'].max()

    # Создаю df с интервалом 
    interval = pd.DateOffset(hour=1)
    time_range = pd.date_range(start=start_time, end=end_time, freq=interval)
        result_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': time_range})
    
    grouped_axis = df.groupby('name')
   
    # создаю пустой df
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for n, group grouped_axis:
        create_axis = result_df.merge(group, on='date', how='left')
        
        # зполняю данными 
        create_axis['name'].fillna(group['name'].iloc[0], inplace=True)
        # Создаю колонку с процентным соотношением
        ratio = np.where(create_axis['total'] != 0,
                                       (create_axis['ok'] / create_axis['ok']) * 100,
                                       np.nan)
        create_axis['ratio'] = activated_ratio


        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, create_axis], ignore_index=True)


    return final_df
```

отображаю `plot` следующим образом

```
initial_data = prepare_axis(df)

unique_names = initial_data['name'].unique()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5), layout='constrained')

for i, name in enumerate(unique_names):
    name_df = initial_data[initial_data['name'] == name].sort_values(by='date')

    ax.plot(name_df['date'], [i or None for i in vendor_df['ratio']], label=name)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d %I%p'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=6))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=3))
ax.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='-')

ax.set_ylabel('%')

fig.legend(loc='outside lower center')


plt.show()
```

на выходе я получаю непрерывный график, просьба, подсказать, где допускаю ошибки, пытаюсь учесть разрывы, чтобы на графике были отражены разрывы где в момент времени нет данных

изначальные данные

```
    data = {
      'date': ['2023-10-23 17:00:00 +0000', '2023-10-23 18:00:00 +0000', '2023-10-23 22:00:00 +0000', '2023-10-23 23:00:00 +0000'],
      'name': ['user1', 'user2', 'user1', 'user1'],
      'total': [23, 54, 564, 222]
      'ok': [2, 1, 45, 125]
}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Вы бы пример исходных данных привели в воспроизводимом формате. Сейчас мало понятно, что вы делаете, но есть подозрение, что много ненужной работы.

Comment: @strawdog, обновил, добавил данные

Comment: Код совершенно нерабочий. Не определено много переменных, есть синтаксические ошибки вроде "for n, group **on** grouped_axis:", а сформированный фрейм initial_data  не используется, вместо него на графике вроде как рисуется исходный необработанный фрейм. Вроде как - потому что этот код не запустится.

Comment: @АлексейР, да, Вы правы при написание немного запутался и опечатался, как раз из опечатки и строился некорректно также добавил [i or None for i in vendor_df['ratio']], буду смотреть дальше где перемудрил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то в общем случае вам достаточно сделать реиндексацию с нужной частотой: вы получите пустые промежутки, которые плоттер будет считать за разрывы:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df = df.set_index("date")
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq="1H"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5), layout='constrained')
ax.plot(df["total"], label=df["name"])
ax.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='-')
ax.set_ylabel('%')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]